# How to integrate reactjs with spring in eclipse?

Tags: reactjs, spring, eclipse, rest

I just realised we use codemix to create react project in eclipse.I want my react frontend to connect with to my backend.I would like to use spring for my backend.How do I make rest calls if my ui is built using react? Can someone please help me providing details on how to build such project?
1)I would like to know how should the project structure be like
2)Where should i write requestmapping uri
3)Will my controller be react code
Thankyou inadvance for your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two projects. One will have back-end code and other will have frond-end code. Back-end will be using Spring and you can deploy it on any server say Tomcat. 
Your frond-end project in react js will run on node and you can use any library for example axios which will call your Spring controller endpoint from react js code.